# Is this git reset --hard <commitID> successful?

Tags: git, github

i wanted to revert to a certain commit with id, say, `123123`. i used the command `git reset --hard 123123`, and according to certain answers on StackOverflow, that should be enough. However, on the github desktop application i am getting the notification that the commit is 3 behind the master and that i should pull from origin to update. The question is, is this a successful revert? Is it gonna "continue" from that commit from 3 commits ago? How to get rid of the "pull from origin" notification? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is successful, and now if you want the remote to be the same you will have to push with force.

Otherwise if you pull you will just restore the commits that you erased!

Comment: Of note would be that if you wanted to preserve the history of those commits you might consider `git revert <commit>...` to instead continue moving "forward" on your branch and simply record reversals of the previous commits.